# App crashes on launch after renaming module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-signing, android-securityexception, android-app-ops

[Here's what my modules look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKBUu.png) 
I changed my module name in Android Studio from app to wear, after I decided to add another module called mobile. I didn't see any issues until my app update got rejected from Play Store.
The Logcat is filled with this error :

```
E  checkOperation
   java.lang.SecurityException: Specified package com.wrejistry.voicerecorder under uid 10332 but it is really 10335
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.verifyAndGetBypass(AppOpsService.java:3944)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.checkOperationUnchecked(AppOpsService.java:2928)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.checkOperationImpl(AppOpsService.java:2911)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.checkOperationInternal(AppOpsService.java:2898)
at com.android.server.appop.AppOpsService.checkOperation(AppOpsService.java:2889)
at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub.onTransact(IAppOpsService.java:425)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1159)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

Is it safe to add a new module for a phone app to my existing project? Did the error occur because I added a new module or is it because I renamed the "app" module to "wear". How do I prevent this issue and make sure the device recognizes my app signature the same as before I changed the module name.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution on this exception? If so, what did you do?

Comment: @TangoBravo I imported an earlier version of my project into Android Studio and abandoned the one that was giving me errors, and then added a new module 
(mobile) without renaming the "app" module. I had to do this because I couldn't fix the error.  So I have 2 modules now, "app" and "mobile". I wanted to have "wear" and "mobile" but renaming the "app" module caused that error so I just left it as "app".